# I-130: Is Beneficiary’s Passport Information Required?

Tags: usa, family

My wife (US citizen) is filing I-130 to petition a green card for her brother. However, her brother doesn’t have a passport.

Question: Is a passport or travel document number required in the application?

If her brother gets a passport, it will expire in 10 years anyways (it takes more than 10 years for a priority date to become current). That just makes me wonder if it is really needed. The passport number will be different when he is ready to immigrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The beneficiary is not required to have a passport to be petitioned.